# a b c triples with bounded prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, abc-conjecture

(i) For any fixed $B>0$, are there only finitely many triples $a,b,c$ of coprime positive integers, such that $a+b=c$ and all prime factors of $a,b,c$ are at most $B$?

(ii) For which $B$ all such triples are known?

A positive answer to (i) would follow from the abc conjecture. For (ii), we may assume $a\leq b$. There is one triple $1+1=2$ for $B=2$. For $B=3$, there are triples $1+1=2$, $1+2=3$, $1+3=4$, and $1+8=9$, and this list in complete. Indeed, the question reduces to equation $1+2^n=3^m$ or $1+3^m=2^n$. These equations has been solved by Gersonides in 1343. What about $B=5$?

Comment: The answer to (i) is yes. Let $S$ be the set of primes at most $B$, so $S$ is a finite set. Then it is a classical result of Siegel-Mahler that the equation $u+v=1$ has only finitely many solutions in $S$-units, i.e., solutions in rational numbers with the numerators and denominators of $u$ and $v$ divisible by only the primes in $S$. This solves your problem by taking $u=a/c$ and $v=b/c$. The original proofs were ineffective, but linear-forms-in-logs give effective versions. I don't know offhand the current answer to (ii).

Comment: Thank you for the answer to (i).

Comment: Matschke and von Kanel have done this for $B=53$; see https://bmatschke.github.io/solving-classical-diophantine-equations/#sunit

Comment: BTW, there's also a conjecture of Erdos, Stewart, and Tijdeman, based on a fairly convincing heuristic argument, that the number of solution using primes {2,3,...,p_n} should grow roughly like C^{n^{1/2}} (I think that's the right exponent, will try to check when I have a chance.)

Comment: @JoeSilverman is your comment related to the xyz conjecture in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closely related is

- Jeffrey C. Lagarias, K. Soundararajan, *Smooth solutions to the abc equation: the xyz Conjecture*,    J. Theor. Nombres Bordeaux 23 (2011), No. 1, 209–234, arXiv:[0911.4147](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4147):

> This paper studies integer solutions to the ABC equation A+B+C=0 in which none of A, B, C has a large prime factor.

Possible answer to your (ii) is on p. 4 of the pdf:

> Example 2. de Weger [31, Theorem 5.4] found the complete set of primitive
> solutions to the xyz equation having S(X, Y, Z) ≤ 13; there are 545 such
> solutions. His table of large solutions ([31, Table IX]) yields the extremal
> values given in Table 1.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed is a complete answer.